# Auto Height Embla Carousel in React

Tags: reactjs, height, carousel, auto

Can anyone help me to get the correct syntax for auto height plugin in my embla carrousel with next JS please ?
I can't figure out why it doesn't work

here is my code :

```
const CarouselDetails = ({
  options = { loop: true, destroyHeight: "auto" },
}) => {
  const autoplay = useRef(
    Autoplay(
      { delay: 5000, stopOnInteraction: false },
      (emblaRoot) => emblaRoot.parentElement
    )
  );
  const autoheight = useRef(AutoHeight((emblaRoot) => emblaRoot.parentElement));

  const [emblaRef, emblaApi] = useEmblaCarousel(
    options,
    [autoplay.current],
    [autoheight.current]
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've misunderstood the [documentation](https://www.embla-carousel.com/get-started/react/#adding-plugins). Here's what the [documentation](https://www.embla-carousel.com/api/plugins/) say:

- *The Embla Carousel constructor accepts an optional plugin array as the third argument, which enables you to extend your carousels with additional features.*

Here are some problems I found with your setup:

- You're adding each plugin in a separate array. All plugins should be in the **same** array.
- The `AutoHeight` plugin doesn't accept a function that returns a root element. This is only available for the `Autoplay` plugin.

Try this:

```js
const CarouselDetails = ({
  options = { loop: true },
}) => {
  const autoheight = useRef(AutoHeight());
  const autoplay = useRef(
    Autoplay(
      { delay: 5000, stopOnInteraction: false },
      (emblaRoot) => emblaRoot.parentElement
    )
  );
  
  const [emblaRef, emblaApi] = useEmblaCarousel(
    options,
    [autoheight.current, autoplay.current],
  );
```